# Conditional count using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements

I have table like below

```
CID ITEM    FLAG
C_1 ITEM_1  0
C_1 ITEM_2  1
C_1 ITEM_2  1
C_1 ITEM_2  0
C_2 ITEM_2  0
C_3 ITEM_2  1
C_3 ITEM_2  1
C_3 ITEM_3  1
```

and I want to produce  table like

```
CID UNIQ_CNT_OF_CID
ITEM_1  0
ITEM_2  2
ITEM_3  1
```

The catch is - I want to count `CID` once for same `CID`.

I tried ,

```
SELECT  ITEM, CID,
      case when FLAG =1 then count(distinct CID)  else 0 end  as COUNTER 
      from T  
      group by ITEM
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question correctly, if not let me know.

You can use a windowed function to accomplish this:

```
SELECT
ITEM,
COUNT(DISTINCT CID) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM) AS UNIQ_CNT_OF_CID
FROM T
```

This will give you the same number of rows, so you if you want the unique from this, you can use a CTE or sub-query it like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ITEM, UNIQ_CNT_OF_CID
FROM
    (
    SELECT
    ITEM,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CID) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM) AS UNIQ_CNT_OF_CID
    FROM T
    ) final
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close. 2 items to point out:

1. The `group by` must contain the same fields in the select (that are not in an aggregate function). since there is no need to group by `CID`, that should be removed from the select.
2. You *can* use `CASE` for fields not in a group by, but **inside** the aggregate function.

So amending your SQL will now look like this:

```
SELECT ITEM,
    -- The CID is used inside the case, inside the count function.
    -- NULL will not be included in the count
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FLAG = 1 THEN CID ELSE NULL END) AS COUNTER 
    from T 
    group by ITEM
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: `NULL will not be included in the count` would be a little more accurate I think, but nicely done.

Comment: @Used_By_Already ah thanks for pointing that out :) amended it.

Comment: How can I include null in the count?